# How can I create a event listener that will execute a function when object A collides with object B?

Tags: actionscript-3

Alright, I've looked online at a bunch of different collision tutorials but they don't explain what I'm looking for. I want object A to hit object B and then execute a function via to a Event listener. Can someone explain and PLEASE provide some source code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Hit Event or such thing in AS. What you can do is to listen to an Enter Frame Event and check the collision.

For e.g.:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkCollision);

function checkCollision(event:Event):void
{
    if(mc1.hitTestObject(mc2)) collisionDetected();
};

function collisionDetected():void
{
    trace("Collision Detected!");
};
```

Rob